# How can i rotate gameobjects back from mirror?

Tags: unity, c#

For some reason when i create the gameobjects they are places like mirror.
And i'm not sure how to rotate them back.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.transform.parent = transform;
            cube.transform.position = new Vector3(pointsList[i].Y, 0, pointsList[i].X);
        }
```

pointsList is a List 
For example in index 4 X = 3 Y = 17

But i'm not sure why it's creating the objects mirrored. And how to rotate it back.

In the screenshot it should be written Hello World but it looks mirror.
The empty GameObject rotation is 0,0,0 and each child Cube rotation also 0,0,0

[image: HW]

Comment: Old post, but probably all is fine and just the camera is facing the wrong direction

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your camera which is wrong.

You probably have your camera placed in a positive z-position pointing in the direction of the negative z-axis. So every new object you place is viewed "from behind". The solution would be to place your camera at a negative z-position and having it face parallel to the z-axis of the scene.

However, if you have a really good reason to composition your scene like this and changing it now would be inconvenient, then I would recommend you to create a prefab "Text" and create all other texts in your game either as instances of that prefab or as prefab-variants of that prefab. That way any change you do to the master "Text" prefab will be applied to all the texts in the game, including changing the rotation. This method also has another great advantage: If you want to try different text styles (font, color, size, etc) you just need to change the basic text prefab and it will automatically be applied to all the texts in the game.

When I design UIs then I usually do that with all the basic UI elements. It makes it a lot easier to retroactively experiment with the visual theme of the game after the UI is already built. Want to try a different design for the buttons? Just change the sprite of the master "Button" prefab and all the buttons in the game now look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Either to change each cube position by adding minus to the X the Z axis: `cube.transform.position = new Vector3(pointsList[i].Y, 0, -pointsList[i].X);` or to rotate the parent GameObject by -180 like this `transform.Rotate(0, 0, -180);`